# Problemas com Datatables usando PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-datatables

eu fiz um sistema, onde o user pode criar tabela para o banco, e tbm pode criar colunas, então, não sei quais as colunas que foram criadas, mas com o script do banco eu consigo listar as colunas desta tabela

estou tentando montar minha tabela da view com `datatables server side`

declaração do datatable js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('table').DataTable({
            "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            responsive: true,
            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
            buttons: [
                {extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile'},
                {extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile'}
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                url :"ajax.php", // json datasource
                type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                success: function(res){
                    return res;
                },
                error: function(err){  // error handling
                    console.log("error", err);
                }
            },
            <?php
            echo "columns: [";
            $query2 = "select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns
                        where table_schema = '$table_schema' AND table_name = '$nList'
                        order by table_name,ordinal_position";
            $query2 = mysql_query($query2);
            $i=0;
            $n = mysql_num_rows($query2);
            while ($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
                $value = $res2["COLUMN_NAME"];
                $i++;
                if ($i == $n) {
                    echo '{ "title": "'.$value.'" }';
                }else{
                    echo '{ "title": "'.$value.'" },';
                }
            }
            echo "]";
            ?>

        });
    });
```

onde $nList é o nome da tabela e $table_schema meu DB

agora la no meu `ajax.php` :

```
    $start = $_REQUEST["start"];
$length = $_REQUEST["length"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM patient_records ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $length";
$query = mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

$totaldata = mysql_num_rows($query);
$totalfiltered = mysql_num_rows($query);

$json_data = array(
    "draw"            => intval( $_REQUEST['draw'] ),
    "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totaldata ),
    "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalfiltered ),
    "data"            => $rows
);

echo json_encode($json_data);
```

no html, o datatable mostra as colunas, mas os dados não:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no meu console, o retorno ta assim dos dados do ajax.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O DataTables já possui algumas formas de você fazer isso. Irei demonstrar uma forma com dados fixos, mas basta alterar para o seu exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var colunas = [{
    title: "Name"
  }, {
    title: "Position"
  }, {
    title: "Office"
  }, {
    title: "Extn."
  }, {
    title: "Start date"
  }, {
    title: "Salary"
  }];

  var data = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
    ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
    ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
    ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
    ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
    ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
    ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
    ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
    ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
    ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
    ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
    ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
    ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
    ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
    ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
    ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
    ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
    ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
    ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
    ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
    ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
    ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
    ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
    ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
    ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
    ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
    ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
    ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
    ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
    ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
    ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
    ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
    ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
  ];

  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: colunas
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="example"></table>
```

Repare que as colunas você já possui, então basta retornar os valores na mesma ordem das colunas.

Como está utilizando PHP, [o DataTables possui um exemplo completo de como utilizar o server-side para isso](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html).

Conselho também a olhar as [implementações via Ajax que o site possui](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/).

No fórum do DataTables você também encontra diversas discussões sobre esse assunto, [como esta daqui.](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29260/dynamic-column-headers-via-ajax)

Você também pode ver [esta mesma implementação neste fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rmcmaster/bbLjzspf/22/)

Comment: obrigado funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Para exibir os dados de retorno das colunas eu geralmente uso no formato:

```
{   'targets': indicedacoluna,  
    "data": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return data['nomedocampo'];
    }
}
```

no seu caso acho que teria que substituir

```
  $i++;
            if ($i == $n) {
                echo '{ "title": "'.$value.'" }';
            }else{
                echo '{ "title": "'.$value.'" },';
            }
```

por:

```
   echo "{  'targets': $i,  
        'data': function ( data, type, row ) {
            return data['$value'];
        }
    }";
    $i++;
    if ($i != $n) echo ',';
```

Não tenho como testar, mas acho que é isso.

Comment: vamos la, no meu js, eu tenho q substituir dentro do columns?

Comment: poderia alterar o codigo para eu ver como fica?